# Prevent in-house iOS app from using a cached version of JSON file

Tags: ios, xamarin, iis, xamarin.ios

I have an in-house iOS app that on launch will check a JSON file to see if there is a new version to download and if it is required or optional.

However, it seems the app is using a cached version of that file to check so it will never see updates. I know how to trick it into never getting a cached version: in the future I will be passing in a timestamp as a parameter to the JSON URL. However, until they get that update I will have this issue. And I want them to be able to get this update without having them re-download the app.

Is there any way to clear the cached version from the iPhone and make sure that the app is not using it? On the server I have already disabled client cache via web.config for the folder the JSON file is in and that didn't solve the issue.

Here is the code I use to check for the updates:

```
protected async override void OnAppearing()
        {

            var CurrentVersion = new Version(DependencyService.Get<IScreen>().Version);



            HelperFile myHelper = new HelperFile();
            //var page = new ContentPage();
            //App.Current.MainPage = page;

            //Pass Information to Webservice
            Uri jsonUrl1 = new Uri(string.Format("https://website.com/mobileapp/VersionNo.json"));

            var result = await myHelper.GetResponseString(jsonUrl1);
            JObject rss = JObject.Parse(result);


            var RecentVersion = new Version((string)rss["version"]);
            var MinimumVersion = new Version((string)rss["minimum"]);
            string ChangeLog = (string)rss["changelog"];
            string ShowChangeLog = (string)rss["showchangelog"];

            var isRequired = CurrentVersion.CompareTo(MinimumVersion);
            var isOptional = CurrentVersion.CompareTo(RecentVersion);
            if (isRequired < 0)
            {

                //go to forced update page
                var updatePopup = new UpdatePopup(false, RecentVersion, MinimumVersion, ChangeLog, ShowChangeLog);
                await Navigation.PushPopupAsync(updatePopup);
            }
            else if (isOptional < 0)
            {
                //go to optional  update page
                var updatePopup = new UpdatePopup(true, RecentVersion, MinimumVersion, ChangeLog, ShowChangeLog);
                await Navigation.PushPopupAsync(updatePopup);
            }
            else
            {
                App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new CheckUpdatedInformation());
            }
        }
```

GetResponseString code:

```
public async Task<string> GetResponseString(Uri url)
        {
            try
            {
                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
                    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url))
                    {
                        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                        {
                            using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                            {
                                string myContent = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                                return myContent;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return "Error";
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Comment: You aren’t showing us the code that does the download or does any caching

Comment: I'm not doing any caching on purpose, and the code that does the download is irrelevant. There is not a problem with the download. The issue is that even though the JSON file itself has a new version listed, it is automatically using a cached version of the JSON file to check the version so it doesn't see updates. It is hitting the "else" part of this if statement. For my phone at least.

Comment: Knowing how you do the download is extremely relevant.  HttpClient, for example, should not do any internal caching.  It’s possible some other mechanisms might, but  I can’t say without knowing what you’re doing.

Comment: @Jason It is not relevant to my issue. The issue isn't that it is downloading a cached update. The issue is that it is not even hitting that part of the code, because it doesn't think it needs to based on the values from a JSON file. It is getting the wrong values from a JSON file and the code for getting those values is listed. It doesn't matter what I am doing after getting those values, that's not the problem.

Comment: Where is it reading a json file?  What part of the code is it “not hitting”?

Comment: @Jason it is parsing the json file into the rss variable in my code... It is not hitting the part of the code that updates the app, in the code listed it will go to the "else" clause despite the JSON file itself having a more recent version. The comparison logic is fine and the update logic is fine, the values that the RecentVersion and MinimumVersion are just wrong and do not reflect the most JSON file on the server.

Comment: from the code you posted, it is parsing the json from a remote url, not a local file.  There is no caching that I can see.  If it is not getting the latest version of that remote file, then the issue is most likely on your server or elsewhere in the network, not in your client code or in iOS.

Comment: @Jason I added an IIS tag in case there is a solution from the server angle, but IIS is not even logging a GET request for the page in these cases and the issue does not happen in a simulator or with colleagues who have not used the app in a while

Comment: again, since you have not shared the code for `GetResponseString` I have no idea what it is doing

Comment: @Jason sorry I did not even realize that function was custom code. I thought you were asking for the code that downloaded the app update. I have included the code for GetResponseString

Comment: You're just using `HttpClient`, I have never had an issue with that caching data

Answer (score 1):

On iOS, if you want to prevent NSUrlSessionHandler from caching requests, you will have to initialize it with `DisableCaching` set to true.

Right now it is implicitly used by your HttpClient, but you will need to do something like:

```cs
_client = new HttpClient(new NSUrlSessionHandler
{ 
    DisableCaching = true
});
```

If you are on MAUI, it is even better to configure a HttpClientFactory which uses this NSUrlSessionHandler and have the factory create instances of HttpClient as needed. Putting HttpClient in a using statement is not recommended. It leaks sockets and could potentially starve your App and Servers you are hitting from sockets.

Comment: Thanks, that is appreciated. Although from what I have read from other issues this caching can still occur with DisableCaching set. I will look into the HttpClientFactory as well. At the moment I am mostly looking for a way to clear the cache so I can roll out these updates without having people re-install.

Comment: Can't you serve the content with no cache headers? Alternatively with E-tag so you can check if you have the latest content?